# Pandas comparing a date to datetime index using if statement

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop, conditional-statements

I'm using a for loop to compare a variable/ date to each datetime period.  The code below produces 'False' for every period, which is incorrect. The first five dates on my list are all in 2006, the last five are all in 2011.  The dtype for data['date'] is datetime64 and I convert the variable to datetime in my code.

Thanks in advance for any help or comments.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

data = pd.read_csv("test_data_3.csv").fillna(0)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data.set_index(data['date'], inplace=True)

lockout_pd_2_begin = '2009-06-01'
lockout_pd_2_begin = datetime.strptime(lockout_pd_2_begin,'%Y-%m-%d')

for row in data:
    if (lockout_pd_2_begin >= data['date']).all():
        data['lockout_test_result'] = 'True'
    else:
        data['lockout_test_result'] = 'False'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get the question right, you simply want a boolean mask. In `pandas` you can derive that using conditionals like

```
# trying to reproduce the data:
data = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range("2006-01-01", "2011-12-31", freq='M')})

# get a boolean Series reflecting the condition:
data['lockout_test_result'] = data['date'] >= pd.Timestamp('2009-06-01')

# data
#          date  lockout_test_result
# 0  2006-01-31                False
# 1  2006-02-28                False
# 2  2006-03-31                False
# 3  2006-04-30                False
# 4  2006-05-31                False
# ..        ...                  ...
# 67 2011-08-31                 True
# 68 2011-09-30                 True
# 69 2011-10-31                 True
# 70 2011-11-30                 True
# 71 2011-12-31                 True

# [72 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: @user11144539: glad I could help! in case you wonder why your version didn't work, it's because for each element of `data['date']` ("row"), you do the comparison to the whole column ("data['date']") and then `.all()` will never return true. It would work if you compare to `row`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I'm moving my modeling from excel to python and using an old structured credit deal for practice.  Thanks again for the help.